# Problema con levantar tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

el error que tengo es que cada vez que trato de levantar mi proyecto con tomcat 8.5 me sale el siguiente error. Como puedo solucionarlo.

```
ene 19, 2017 4:52:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
GRAVE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1190)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1458)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:578)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

ene 19, 2017 4:52:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
ADVERTENCIA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (28, 66) :org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
ene 19, 2017 4:52:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester   startElement
GRAVE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1190)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1458)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:578)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:643)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

ene 19, 2017 4:52:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
ADVERTENCIA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (28, 66) :    org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
ene 19, 2017 4:52:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Server.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  --><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
  define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
  Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
  --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
  Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
  <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by  
  UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
  -->
  <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="  org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="  org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
  a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
  so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
  Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
  -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

  <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
  <!--
  <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
  maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
  -->


  <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
  and responses are returned. Documentation at :
  Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
  Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
  APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
  Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
  -->
  <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
  <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
  <!--
  <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="8443" />
  -->
  <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
  This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
  style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
  OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
  documentation -->
  <!--
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
  maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
  -->

  <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


  <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
  every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
  analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
  on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
  Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

  <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
  -->
  <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
  /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
  /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
  via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
  <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
  resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
  that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
  available for use by the Realm.  -->

  <!--         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>  -->

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"  
  connectionURL="ldap://192.168.10.3:389"
  roleBase="ou=group,dc=arkkosoft,dc=com" 
  roleName="cn" 
  roleSearch="(memberUid={1})" 
  userPattern="uid={0},ou=People,dc=arkkosoft,dc=com"/> 
  </Realm>

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

  <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
  Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
  -->

  <!-- Access log processes all example.
  Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
  Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %%b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="rooms-web" path="/rooms-web" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:rooms-web">
  <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="4" maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000"
  name="jdbc/roomsds" password="JDiaz" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/salas" username="root"/>
  </Context>   

  </Host>
  </Engine>
  </Service>
  </Server>
```

Comment: ¿Has modificado a mano el server.xml? Si es así, copialo aquí.

Comment: @pablo                                                                                                                                      ya agregue el server

Comment: O no lo has pegado entero o tienes el fichero mal, cortado

Comment: @pablo ya edite

Comment: Tienes esta linea en tu server.xml? https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bamboo-does-not-start-after-upgrade-due-to-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-catalina-core-jasperlistener-836599885.html

Comment: si la tengo porque?

Comment: sigue sin estar entero, te falta bastante por la parte de arriba. No es que sea información necesaria, pero si no tienes ese cacho el fichero no será válido

Comment: pero no tengo nada relacionado con bamboo

Comment: @pablo listo ahora si?

Comment: en la carpeta de tomcat, entra a lib, dime si tienes algun jar de catalina es decir algo asi: catalina.jar o catalina-version.jar

Comment: tengo                               
Catalina.jar
Catalina-ant.jar
Catalina-storeconfig.jar
Catalina-tribes.jar

Comment: No tienes el server.xml del tomcat original, acabo de bajarme un tomcat 8.5 y es muy diferente,¿lo has tocado a mano?

Comment: Basicamente se esta quejando que no encuentra la  clase, abre tu catalina.jar, sigue esta ruta org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener y si no encuenytras el .class, descargate este jar : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcatalina6026jar.htm y pegalo en esa capeta(ojo solo el catalaina-version.jar), copiata el catalina.jar en otro sitio por si acaso

Comment: Has cambiado el server.xml, ¿sigue arrancando mal ahora?

Comment: si, lo he editado pero con tomcat 7 no sale ese problema

Comment: ¿Qué error da ahora? Un server.xml no tiene por qué ser compatible para tomcat 7 y 8.

Comment: al agregar el catalina. jar que descargue, es de tomcat 6

Comment: con tomcat 7 el unico problema es que no me deja ver mi pagina de inicio pero al menos si levanta

Comment: ¿Qué error da con el 8?

Comment: ¿Has intentado descargar Tomcat 8.5 nuevamente e iniciar de nuevo? ¿Necesitas modificar la instalación de tomcat?

Comment: @pablo que el server no esta configurado y ahorita trate con 8.5 e igual

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si ya descargue el 8.5 y sale lo mismo

Comment: Esta liena la tienes porque tu war usa jasper?:
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>, yo tengo un tomcat 8 y no tengo esa linea en mi serve.xml

Comment: No sé qué versión has decargado, pero la que me ha bajado yo (8.5.11) no tiene ninguna referencia a org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener en el server.xml

Comment: ¿Tu proyecto usa reportes hechos en Jasper y también usa Jasper para generarlos y luego descargarlos como PDF, quizás? ¿Has agregado las librerías de Jasper en tu proyecto web dentro de WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @pablo es el server de otro sistema que utiliza el 7 pero lo queria levantar con 8.5 pero me salieron esos problemas.. originalmente en 8.5 no trae nada de jasper

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza por el momento no utilizo nada de eso

Comment: Ya elimine la linea de código pero me tira el otro problema

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/99484)